# Ionic throws TypeError: Cannot read property 'expire' of null when changing view

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

My ionic app throws the following errors whenever I change views and I can't find why, anybody knows what am I doing wrong?

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'expire' of null
    at file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:43339:37
    at Scope.$broadcast (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:23547:28)
    at $state.transition.resolved.then.$state.transition (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:41017:22)
    at processQueue (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:22016:27)
    at file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:22032:27
    at Scope.$eval (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:23228:28)
    at Scope.$digest (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:23044:31)
    at Scope.$apply (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:23333:24)
    at file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:25059:36
    at completeOutstandingRequest (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13732:10)
ionic.bundle.js (20434,24)
```

Comment: Hi, did you find out what was causing it? I am running into the same problem. For me it happens only when I am clicking on ionic side menu items. Without those and using only ui-router ui-sref links it was working fine. Seems like something between ui-router and the ionic side menu is not working properly in my case. What version of ui-router and ionic are you working with? I am using ui-router v0.2.15 (release) and ionic v1.0.1. May be worthwhile checking whether either project has had some fixes.

Comment: And I have the opposite happen on my program - ui-srefs in main view throw with the same traceback, sigh.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So as I wrote in the comment, I had the same issue and it looks it's a bug in ionic v1.0.1. Somewhere here in the thread in the link below, it is suggested that the problem manifests itself when using ionic's "menu-close" attribute:

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/4038

After changing the "menu-close" to "menu-toggle" the problem disappeared and for me this is good enough. I guess a fix will be committed shortly.

Hope it helps!